# How automatically call destructor in qt when I want to exit the application?

Tags: c++, qt

I use CAMA series (finger print module) for my application. In that document it said that recommended to use `EnrollStandByMode` command before exit the application. I create this command and call it in my destructor on QMainWindow in my application. (there is no problem here). But when I exit the application and again run it my finger print is confused and the response commands are incorrect.  After trace my code ,I saw the destructor not run when the application close with close button.

This is my code to exit the qapp.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    qDebug()«"QApplication::quit()";
    QApplication::quit();
}
```

I want to know how to call destructor before exit the application?

Comment: Not sure this will work, so not an answer, but how about a class whose sole purpose is to call EnrollStandByMode in the destructor, and then have a global variable of that class?  The C++ run time library should invoke the destructors of all global variables (but beware that some other globals may already have been destructed, so be careful).

Comment: you mean at first I create a class that just call this method, then I make a global variable to call it?so how can it help me? could you explain it?tnx in advance

Comment: @H.Ghassami I've just seen that you call explicitly `QApplication::quit();`. Why don't you simply close the window within `on_pushButton_clicked`. Application will be over in both cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to call something at the end of the application.

If your code does not require the Qt event loop to run, just call the function at the end of `main()`

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv); // or QGuiApplication/QCoreApplication

    // application setup

    const int resultCode = app.exec();

    // call your shutdown code here

    return resultCode;
}
```

Another option is to register a function with `qAddPostRoutine()` which is called by the Qt application object's destructor.

If you need the Qt event loop, connect a function to the Qt application object's `aboutToQuit()` signal.